# How to create create spoofing url or something like this in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to make dynamic URL which is:

```
<li><a href="{{url("test/$test->id")}}">{{$test->test_name}}</a></li>
```

which give me me result on hover like this:

```
test/1
test/2
test/3
```

whereas i want something like this

```
test/abc
test/def
test/xyz
```

but want to fetch data on the base of id so how can i get data using id but on url show lasomething else

Route

```
Route::get('/test/{id}','Frontend\HomePageController@profile');
```

Comment: Hey Arfa, Did my answer help with your problem?

Comment: yeah it does but at some level is use you option 2 but u did't wrote it in a clear way but anyhow i get an idea from that how to do it.

Comment: Feel free to edit my answer to make it clearer. I thought giving an example snippet and a link to the official documentation would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install this package

[Laravel Hashids](https://github.com/vinkla/laravel-hashids)

Then after successful installation in your profile method do this to fetch the data from the DB

```
$decodedId = Hashids::decode($id)[0];
```

Then in your view in the loop do this

```
$encodedId = Hashids::encode($test->id);

<li><a href="{{url("test/$encodedId")}}">{{$test->test_name}}</a></li>
```

You can dump the var to see what's going on

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to make a route like this:

```
Route::get('test/{test}', 'TestController@show')->name('test.show');
```

And then in your views you can do this:

```
<a href="{{ Route('test.show', $test) }}">{{ $test->name }}</a>
```

There are at least 2 options:

**Option 1**

You can register a binding in the Route Service provider.

In `RouteServiceProvider` do something like this:

```
Route::bind('test', function ($slug) {
    return \App\Test::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();
});
```

Assuming you have an Eloquent model for `Test` that contains a unique field (I've used `slug`) to grab the entry by.

This tutorial covers is quite well: https://mattstauffer.co/blog/implicit-model-binding-in-laravel-5-2/

**Option 2**

Another way. If you know you will never want to refer to the `id` of the test in the URL and always want to refer to another unique field (eg `slug`), you can customise which key name is used by Laravel by overriding the getRouteKeyName() method on the model.

```
/**
 * Get the route key for the model.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}
```

See documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-model-binding